# Angular Material stepper title disappears when screen is too small

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

I am using a vertical stepper and it works fine for computer screens. However, when using a screen that is too small to display all of the title at once, it gets replaced with `...`.

How can I get it to use line breaks rather that hide the title?

The code I am using:

```
    <mat-step [completed]="true" *ngFor="let experience of experiences" state="check" >
      <ng-template matStepLabel>
        <img class="logo title-content-element vertical-align" src="{{experience.logoPath}}"/>
        <div class="spacer title-content-element vertical-align"></div>
        <div class="spacer title-content-element vertical-align"></div>
        <div class="title-content-element vertical-align">
          <h6 class="title-content-element no-margin">{{experience.type}} - {{experience.title}}</h6>
          <br />
          <span class="italic-text title-content-element">
            <span [innerHTML]="experience.dateStart.replace('/', ' / ')"></span> -
            <span [innerHTML]="experience.dateEnd.replace('/', ' / ')"></span>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <span [innerHTML]="this.getDuration(experience.dateStart, experience.dateEnd)"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <p [innerHTML]="experience.description"></p>
    </mat-step>
```

It yields the following :

[image: big screen normal display]

But on small screens it gets truncated:

[image]

How can I rather get a carriage return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this (by guessing your current CSS), is to add some extra CSS to override the default Angular Material `mat-stepper` CSS.

```css
.mat-step-label.mat-step-label {
  text-overflow: inherit;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

will be enough to overrule the default CSS and to not have ellipsis on your titles (via `text-overflow`). [See the difference in this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xunv9e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstepper-vertical-example.html) that has two examples of the Material stepper:

1. Not wrapping to next line
2. Wrapping to next line

Answer (score 0):

I had to change it since now you cannot style it directly, had to add ::ng-deep. This allows you to "punch through" and style things that are outside your view to edit. Here is a good article about it.
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/

:host is added to limit it to only change it in this context and not globally.

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-step-text-label {
  text-overflow: inherit;
  white-space: normal;
}
```